# How to get XLS file from HTML event directly into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to download a XLS file from [a website](https://nl.espacenet.com/searchResults?submitted=true&locale=nl_NL&DB=EPODOC&ST=advanced&TI=&AB=&PN=&AP=&PR=&PD=&PA=Coca%20Cola&IN=&CPC=&IC=) with Selenium automation (why Selenium you might ask, that is because I have to actively load more content for export on the result page.)

The button in questions is on the top of the website stating XLS next to Exporteer.
I succeeded to download the XLS files in question with Selenium by using:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.exportLink:nth-child(3)").click()
```

However, downloading 10 seperate XLS files, reading them in again in Python for modifications and saving them back is time consuming, and non-efficient.

I am now trying to directly read this XLS file into a pandas dataframe in Python with the following method but only with half success:

```
from io import StringIO
from seleniumrequests import Firefox
import pandas as pd
import os
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver = Firefox()
Requests="https://nl.espacenet.com/searchResults?submitted=true&locale=nl_NL&DB=EPODOC&ST=advanced&TI=&AB=&PN=&AP=&PR=&PD=&PA=Coca+Cola&IN=&CPC=&IC="
webdriver.get(Requests)
r = webdriver.request('GET',"https://nl.espacenet.com/exportExcelResultsList?locale=nl_NL")
data = r.content
toread = io.BytesIO()
toread.write(data)
toread.seek(0)
df = pd.read_excel(toread)
df
```

It actually manages to pull something, but not the results:

```
Unnamed: 0  Unnamed: 1  Unnamed: 2  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Unnamed: 5  Unnamed: 6  Unnamed: 7  Unnamed: 8  Unnamed: 9  ...     Unnamed: 14     Unnamed: 15     Unnamed: 16     Unnamed: 17     Unnamed: 18     Unnamed: 19     Unnamed: 20     Unnamed: 21     Unnamed: 22     Unnamed: 23
0   Ongeveer 9.865 treffers in databank Worldwide ...   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   Coca Cola als aanvrager     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   Displaying selected publications    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   Titel   Publicatienummer    Publicatiedatum     Uitvinder(s)    Aanvrager(s)    IPC     Cooperative Patent Classification   Aanvraagnummer  Aanvraagdatum   Prioriteitsnummer(s)    ...     OTHER PATENT CITATIONS  OTHER LITERATURE CITATIONS  PATENTS USED IN OPPOSITION  LITERATURE USED IN OPPOSITION   PATENTS CITED BY THE APPLICANT  LITERATURE CITED BY THE APPLICANT   International search citation   International search NPL citation   Supplementary international search citation     Supplementary international search NPL citation

4 rows × 24 columns
```

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: which ten in particular?

Comment: For example ten companies just like COCA COLA from the example as FANTA, SPRITE, ICETEA, FERNANDES. The real use case example is much more complex but that seems irrelevant?

Comment: Ok, phrased differently, are the fields within the files the same across all items you wish to combine into a single dataframe?

Comment: Yes, every XML file retrieved from this website should have the same columns with information!